# Actions on Google where to start with no experience in JSON

Tags: actions-on-google

Where I can learn about actions on google? I have read the documentations but still confused I don't have any experience in JSON

Comment: What language and web server technologies are you familiar working with? What are you trying to do that you feel you need to use server fulfillment?

Comment: I don't get it. JSON is a data description language....like XML, so whats the point here?

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google provides a convenient Node.js client library, which handles all the Conversation API JSON payloads for you. You can just use the high-level client library API instead: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading about JSON and understanding it, you should probably get to know some basic JavaScript.
This is a very basic getting started website:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

If your using Java or Kotlin (or any lang on JVM really) you can use the unofficial Kotlin/Java SDK - https://github.com/TicketmasterMobileStudio/actions-on-google-kotlin